# a Jenkins job for every pull request

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I want to do a very simple thing - for every new pull request that is being created under my repo, I want to create a new jenkins job with similer configuration (run some batch), that will checkout the branch that is being merged (not the destination branch).

I will also like to delete this job after the pull request is approved, but that's not as important.

How do I do that? Every jenkins plugin that I found creates jobs for all my branches, or for a specified list of branches, instead of just for new ones or just unmerged pull requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally succeseeded, and it was WAY EASIER then I thought. I found a jenkins plugin called "Bitbucket pullrequest builder plugin", and it makes it incrediblly ease to build jobs for pull requests. The only thing is that I couldn't make it work with any OAuth consumer, and had to give it my own credentials. But other then that it works beautifully.

Comment: add a link to the plugin, maybe?

Comment: Is it still working? Could you please provide version numbers of jenkins, bitbucket (cloud? on promise?) and plugin? Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question @chrispolzer. Recently I tried configuring this plugin, but it didn't work.

Comment: @chrispolzer It works for me with following versions: Jenkins 2.60.1, bitbucket-pullrequest-builder 1.4.26 and Bitbucket Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you could solve this:

1. Create a template job containing the logic you want to do for each new branch (i.e. run some batch).
2. Create a job that is started for every new pull request in your repo.  You could probably do this with the [Script SCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+SCM+Plugin) using a short groovy script.
3. Inside this triggered job, clone the job in #1 using the [Jobcopy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jobcopy+Builder+plugin).  Replace any strings (e.g. git url) with whatever is needed to get the job working.
4. You could write another job that is triggered via the Script SCM Plugin when a branch needs to be deleted. You can remove it using the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

Comment: But will this give me the branch that is being merged, or the branch that it's merged to? The problem is "whatever is needed to get the job working" is a dynamic branch name.

Comment: The plugin is open ended, so which one it would return would be dependent on how you code it.  If you wanted to get the branch that is being merged, you could do that and vice versa..  It can run a custom script, so how it functions is entirely up to you and how the script is written.

Comment: Regarding the clarification of "whatever is needed to get the job working" comment, the jobcopy plugin just replaces strings in one job's config with whatever you tell it to.  So, you would probably update the Job's project name, the git url, the batch command parameters (and anything else you need)..  Again, this is entirely up to you how the template job gets transformed into a working job..

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how I'm suppose to get the name of the branch. I get how to run a jenkins job when branch X is requesting a merge into branch Y, and I get how to create a new job with different parameters, but I don't know how to get the name of branch X.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar with what we did in our team (We have more than 10 development branches and also a lot release branches)

I think the easiest way is as follows:

Plugin should be used:

[gerrit trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger)
Used to get triggered when there is new commit come in

[job dsl plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)
Used to generate the jobs based on the dsl script

[build flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)
Used to define the execution flow

1. Create a Jenkins build flow job "EntryPoint" (This job will be triggered if there is a new commit push for review)
2. Create the a job generator job (This job will invoke the job dsl script to generate the template jobs based on the input parameter, such as branch)
3. Create a new job to do the cleanup work or as Daniel said, you can do it with groovy post build
4. Inside the build flow job, a simple flow as follows

   ```
   //Get current branch from gerrit trigger plugin
   def currentBranch = params[GERRIT_BRANCH]
   //Invoke job generator job and pass the branch info to it
   build ("job_generator",BRANCH:currentBranch )
   //Invoke the generated job by job_generator
   build("$currentBrnch_Build")
   //Remove the generated job
   build("CleanUpJob")
   ```

Comment: But will this give me the branch that is being merged, or the branch that it's merged to?

Comment: If you mean which code it checkout, then it is the commit you pushed.

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how I'm suppose to get the name of the branch. I get how to run a jenkins job when branch X is requesting a merge into branch Y, and I get how to create a new job with different parameters, but I don't know how to get the name of branch X.

Comment: If this is the case, then you should generate the JobBranchY instead of JobBranchX